# Django Form based on Form

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am writing my code based on the principle don't repeat yourself. I keep violating that rule because I am new to Django but this one should be straight forward.

The code below is no problem for ModelAForm:

model.py

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
     id = model.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     name1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     name2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     ...
     right = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ModelB(models.Model):
     id = model.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     mod = model.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     above30 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

forms.py

```
class ModelAForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        exclude = ['id']

class ModelBForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        exclude = ['id']
```

But this way I don't see the other fields of modelA in the ModelBForm. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it should not. Because its FK relation between ModelB and ModelA. So in ModelB form, the ModelA entries should appear as a choice field. If you want to show fields of ModelA then try like this:

First, remove the FK reference field from ModelBForm:

```
class ModelBForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        exclude = ['id', 'mod']
```

Now Use both those forms in your view:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'form_a': ModelAForm(), 'form_b': ModelBForm()}) 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_a = ModelAForm(request.POST)
        form_a = ModelBForm(request.POST)
        if form_a.is_valid() and form_a.is_valid():
            instance_a = form_a.save()  # get model a instance
            instance_b = form_b.save(commit=False)
            instance_b.mod = instance_a  # set model a instance as FK
            instance_b.save()
```

Render the Form Like this:

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_a.as_p }}
    {{ form_b.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: OK thanks I will try that. But this a little to complicated, and it shouldn't be.

Comment: It works thanks. I should have thought of this, I just thought there might be an easier way.